# Track SnapEngage events in Google Analytics when using GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to have SnapEngage chat events recorded in GA following their instructions here: http://help.snapengage.com/how-do-i-track-snapengage-events-in-google-analytics/ 
I'm using Universal Analytics through Google Tag Manager and the events are not recorded in GA reports. They mention that in this case the events are not sent from the browser correctly and suggest as solution to set a Tracker Name in GTM's advanced settings. Is this the only way to make this work? GTM says that "Use of named trackers is highly discouraged" - https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2574372#TrackerName

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your SnapEngage chat implementation looks like, nor am I familiar with SnapEngage chat, but according to the documentation you referenced, you should just be able to swap out `_gaq.push()` for `dataLayer.push()`.

For example, this is what SnapEngage gives you (ga.js):

```
var seAgent;
SnapABug.setCallback('OpenProactive', function(agent, msg) {
    seAgent = agent;
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'SnapEngage', 'proactivePrompt', agent]);
});

SnapABug.setCallback('StartChat', function(email, msg, type) {
    if (type == 'proactive') {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'SnapEngage', 'proactiveEngaged', seAgent]);
    }
});
```

To make this GTM compatible, swap-out the _gaq.push's:

```
var seAgent;
SnapABug.setCallback('OpenProactive', function(agent, msg) {
    seAgent = agent;
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'snapEngageEvent',
        'eventCategory': 'SnapEngage',
        'eventAction': 'proactivePrompt',
        'eventLabel': agent
    });
});

SnapABug.setCallback('StartChat', function(email, msg, type) {
    if (type == 'proactive') {
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'snapEngageEvent',
            'eventCategory': 'SnapEngage',
            'eventAction': 'proactiveEngaged',
            'eventLabel': seAgent
        });        
    }
});
```

Then, within GTM, you'll have to create a new tag for all of your events:

[image]

Note: {{eventCategory}}, {{eventAction}}, and {{eventLabel}} are all dataLayer Variables, so you'll need to create those.

Then and finally, create your rule:

[image]